# Laravel Edit Auth Middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to edit the main `Authenticate.php` middleware, but when I add the following, I get an error

> app.app has redirected you too many times

My intent here is to edit the auth middleware to check if the user has a username. This would prevent someone from exiting the registration page and then simply going into a secure portion of the website.

Auth Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('/');
        }
    }

    // This is the modified portion. Check for a username, if one is found, complete 
       the request, otherwise redirect back to the oauth page.

    if (Auth::user()->username)
    {
        return $next($request);  
    }

    return redirect()->route('oauth.oauth')->with('user' , Auth::user()->id);

}
```

Comment: What is the use case for this? If you want to prevent someone from going to a secure part of the site then you can just use the middleware as is - it already checks if they are a guest, and if they are it redirects them to the homepage (which you can change if needed).

Comment: There are 2 stages in registration, 1st is the email, password, etc. 2nd is an OAuth with outside service. If user exits before completing OAuth, I want to send them back to that page if they try to open up any part of the  website again. Since dozens of routes use the auth middleware, I'd like to modify that instead of making a new one to apply everywhere.

Comment: Is that route protected by this authentication middleware?

Comment: Yes, it is protected by this middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a circular reference by using the auth middleware to redirect them to your oauth page when `Auth::user()->username` isn't present.

They are hitting the oauth page and then failing that check and so being constantly redirected to that page.

The best thing to do would be to split this out in the new middleware, but given you don't want to do this you could check the URL that they are hitting and make an exclusion based on this.

For example:

Add `use Request;` up the top and then in the body of your middleware add the below:

```
if (Request::path() == 'your/oauth/path')
{
    return $next($request);
}
```

So it could fit in like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('/');
        }
    }

    // This is the modified portion. Check for a username, if one is found, complete 
       the request, otherwise redirect back to the oauth page.

    if (Auth::user()->username)
    {
        return $next($request);  
    }

    if (Request::path() == 'your/oauth/path')
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect()->route('oauth.oauth')->with('user' , Auth::user()->id);

}
```

Just replace the `'your/oauth/path'` with the actual path. That example would look like this as a full url `www.example.com/your/oauth/path`